# Why does chr() return a hex value and how can i make it only return characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code i am trying to make a simple encryption software. I want some ideas for a solution to remove the hex values and change them to another value but i want to be able to get these values back.

Input:

```
a = ['123', '12', '103']
a = [int(i) for i in a]
a = [chr(i) for i in a]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['{', '\x0c', 'g']
```

Comment: what you want is not really clear, what is the **expected** output?

Comment: a = [str(i) for i in a] ???

Comment: I have added expected output. Please reopen the question.

Comment: @Harsha Not really what OP was/is asking in the question title…

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Let's wait for the author to provide the expected output instead of guessing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
>>> a = ['123', '12', '103']
>>> a = [chr(int(i)) for i in a]
>>> a
['{', '\x0c', 'g']
>>> b = [str(ord(i)) for i in a]
>>> b
['123', '12', '103']
```